GRPC-cpp : Completion Queue does not return events leading to hang
I have GRPC client in CPP and GRPC server in golang. I use async communication from GRPC client to communicate with server. Both talk using unix domain socket. I use GRPC completion queue to track read/write using tags and wait for tags to be returned/finished from the completion queue.
Lately I have been experiencing hang issue where client does not receive completed events and completion queue indefinitely waits and program runs forever.
I0000 00:00:1722656799.932879   23640 completion_queue.cc:940] PENDING TAGS: 0x7fbb882145a0 0x7fbb88214290
I0000 00:00:1722656799.944181   23640 completion_queue.cc:940] PENDING TAGS: 0x7fbb882145a0 0x7fbb88214290
I0000 00:00:1722656799.944467   23640 completion_queue.cc:940] PENDING TAGS: 0x7fbb882145a0 0x7fbb88214290
I0000 00:00:1722656799.955819   23640 completion_queue.cc:940] PENDING TAGS: 0x7fbb882145a0 0x7fbb88214290
I0000 00:00:1722656799.956277   23640 completion_queue.cc:940] PENDING TAGS: 0x7fbb882145a0 0x7fbb88214290
I0000 00:00:1722656799.967603   23640 completion_queue.cc:940] PENDING TAGS: 0x7fbb882145a0 0x7fbb88214290
I0000 00:00:1722656799.967940   23640 completion_queue.cc:940] PENDING TAGS: 0x7fbb882145a0 0x7fbb88214290
I0000 00:00:1722656799.979248   23640 completion_queue.cc:940] PENDING TAGS: 0x7fbb882145a0 0x7fbb88214290
I0000 00:00:1722656799.979587   23640 completion_queue.cc:940] PENDING TAGS: 0x7fbb882145a0 0x7fbb88214290

I have verified that golang server is sending the required response.
When QUEUE is shutdown using ctrl+c signal, at that time all pending tags are returned normally with the data which they are supposed to have.
Using grpc trace logs, I have verified that when golang server sends the signal, at the time some read call happens on the the client socket.
I0000 00:00:1722656808.248956   34264 chttp2_transport.cc:2821] unix:/var/opt/rt_20_0/runtime.sock: Complete BDP ping err=OK
I0000 00:00:1722656808.248971   34264 bdp_estimator.cc:50] bdp[unix:/var/opt/rt_20_0/runtime.sock]:complete acc=44 est=65536 dt=4.999705 bw=0.000070Mbs bw_est=0.000000Mbs
I0000 00:00:1722656808.248982   34264 bdp_estimator.cc:77] bdp[unix:/var/opt/rt_20_0/runtime.sock]:update_inter_time to 219ms
I0000 00:00:1722656813.248585   31848 tcp_posix.cc:858] READ 0x7fbb8802b360 (peer=unix:/var/opt/rt_20_0/runtime.sock) error=OK
I0000 00:00:1722656813.248598   31848 tcp_posix.cc:864] READ DATA: 00 00 18 01 05 00 00 00 01 40 88 9a ca c8 b2 12 34 da 8f 01 30 40 89 9a ca c8 b5 25 42 07 31 7f 00 00 00 04 03 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 '.........@......4...0@.....%B.1...............'

Any hints what could be going wrong here?
